# playNextVideo Youtube swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, video, youtube

Hello I'm trying to play a series of videos that were searched by the user and it shows a table view with the results and I'm pushing a new view that plays the video. I'm trying to implement play next and previous video functionally by pressing a button.

I have come so far that in didSelectRowAt I only get the id of the video of the video I pressed and the video after that code below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        videoId = videos[indexPath.row].id.videoId
        videosTitle = videos[indexPath.row].snippet.title
        videosChannelTitle = videos[indexPath.row].snippet.channelTitle
        nextVideoId = videos[indexPath.row + 1].id.videoId

        vc.videoTitle = videosTitle
        vc.videoID = videoId
        vc.videoChannelTitle = videosChannelTitle
        vc.nextVideoID = nextVideoId

//        print(videoId)

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
```

I play the video by the following code

```
@objc func playNextVideo() {

        guard let nextVideo = nextVideoID else { return }

        playVideo(videoId: nextVideo)


        }
```

here is the playVideo function

```
func playVideo(videoId: String) {

        let videoEmbdedString = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(String(describing: VidWidth))' height='\(String(describing: VidHeight))' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoId)?enablejsapi=1&controls=0&autohide=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'&controls=0></body></html>"

        VideoWebView.loadHTMLString(videoEmbdedString, baseURL: nil)

    }
```

So I can only play the video I pressed and the video after that, and it makes sense but how can I get the id after that because after I have pressed the button and it plays the next video, but when I press it again it plays the same video again. how can I update what row I'm at though I have  dismissed the view

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have set the `nextVideoId` in `tableViewDidSelect`. And whenever you are clicking on play next button it retrieves that `nextVideoId` only everytime.

You have to update the `nextVideoId` everytime you play next video, i.e. in `playNextVideo()` like this:

```
...
guard let nextVideo = nextVideoId else { return }
// Here you should update the nextVideoId
// Like nextVideoId = videos[selectedIndexStoredInTheClass].id.videoId
....
```